# How to check empty datatables using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-validate

I want validate my table if empty. my table using datatables to add data.

```
<form method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="txt" required>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
<button id="button" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var grid = $('#table').DataTable();

  grid.row.add([
    '1',
    'Jake',
    'England'
  ]).draw(false);

  $("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

If input. I'm just add required attribute. but how to check `datatables` if the table empty. If I'm not add some item. It's will be return message error in above table or top table

**NB:** this how to check datatables empty `table.data().any()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden dummy `input` element. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="table_required">
```

Then use custom function as one of your validation rules.

```
$("#form").validate({
   rules: {
      table_required: {
         required: function(){
            return $('#table').DataTable().data().any();
         }
      }
   },
   submitHandler: function (form) {
      form.submit();
   }
});
```